# Hyperledger on mac using Docker images cannot find Docker daemon?

Tags: macos, docker, hyperledger

I am following this article : https://developer.ibm.com/opentech/2016/06/27/running-hyperledger-fabric-natively-on-mac/

then I got this error :
15:32:16.165 [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 052 Error building images: cannot connect to Docker endpoint

It seems that the Docker daemon is not accessible from the running container. The config points to CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://127.0.0.1:2375

I have a Mac using "Docker Beta"

Any idea ?

Comment: Try using this value instead: CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///var/run/docker.sock - if that works, I need to update my article

Comment: launchAndWaitForRegister failed Error starting container: Post http://unix.sock/containers/create?name=dev-jdoe-95914b788029573695e31d98072a14343b6bbe10b7bf9cce3298db0ebfcf477324c6b7b07867b4439c0918fba1c0d7e725bc06f90f081f21a72f430dae9cbea6: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory

Comment: path /var/run/docker.sock exists   :/

Comment: If i remove the 'unix:///' and just add /var/run/docker.sock , I have another error :    ERRO 068 Error when querying chaincode: Error:Failed to launch chaincode spec(Error starting container: invalid endpoint)

Comment: The socket is in 'write' for root user only. Are you sending data to the socket ?

Answer (score 0):

if your CORE_VM_ENDPOINT is a sock file, you need to mouth /var/run/docker.sock into peer container.
Add the lines below into docker-compose.yml to mouth /var/run/docker.sock

```
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```